# Prisma model is not accessible using Prisma Client?

Tags: typescript, postgresql, next.js, prisma, next.js13

I'm trying to query a property of a Prisma model with Prisma Client. The model is a restaurant model which has a `reviews` property. The `reviews` property is also related to a `Review` model.

### `schema.prisma` file:

```
// This is your Prisma schema file,
// learn more about it in the docs: https://pris.ly/d/prisma-schema

generator client {
  provider = "prisma-client-js"
}

datasource db {
  provider = "postgresql"
  url      = env("DATABASE_URL")
}

model Restaurant {
  id          Int      @id @default(autoincrement())
  name        String
  main_img    String
  images      String[]
  description String
  price       PRICE
  opens_at    String
  closes_at   String
  slug        String   @unique
  created_at  DateTime @default(now())
  updated_at  DateTime @updatedAt
  item        Item[]
  location_id Int      @unique
  location    Location @relation(fields: [location_id], references: [id])
  cuisine_id  Int      @unique
  cuisine     Cuisine  @relation(fields: [cuisine_id], references: [id])
  review_id   Int      @unique
  reviews     Review[]
}

model Item {
  id            Int        @id @default(autoincrement())
  name          String
  price         String
  description   String
  created_at    DateTime   @default(now())
  updated_at    DateTime   @updatedAt
  restaurant_id Int
  restaurant    Restaurant @relation(fields: [restaurant_id], references: [id])
}

model Location {
  id         Int          @id @default(autoincrement())
  name       String
  restraunts Restaurant[]
  created_at DateTime     @default(now())
  updated_at DateTime     @updatedAt
}

model Cuisine {
  id         Int          @id @default(autoincrement())
  name       String
  restraunts Restaurant[]
  created_at DateTime     @default(now())
  updated_at DateTime     @updatedAt
}

model User {
  id         Int      @id @default(autoincrement())
  first_name String
  last_name  String
  city       String
  email      String
  password   String
  phone      String
  review     Review[]
  created_at DateTime @default(now())
  updated_at DateTime @updatedAt
}

model Review {
  id            Int        @id @default(autoincrement())
  first_name    String
  last_name     String
  rating        RATING
  text          String
  restaurant_id Int
  restaurant    Restaurant @relation(fields: [restaurant_id], references: [id])
  user_id       Int
  user          User       @relation(fields: [user_id], references: [id])
  created_at    DateTime   @default(now())
  updated_at    DateTime   @updatedAt
}

enum PRICE {
  CHEAP
  REGULAR
  HIGH
  EXPENSIVE
}

enum RATING {
  HALF
  ONE
  ONE_HALF
  TWO
  TWO_HALF
  THREE
  THREE_HALF
  FOUR
  FOUR_HALF
  FIVE
}
```

I'm trying to query this schema from a `page.tsx` file using Prisma client.

### Query with Prisma Client:

```
import { PrismaClient, Cuisine, Location, PRICE, Review } from "@prisma/client";

const prisma = new PrismaClient();

export interface IRestaurantCardType {
  id: number;
  name: string;
  price: PRICE;
  main_img: string;
  location: Location;
  cuisine: Cuisine;
  slug: string;
  reviews: Review[];
}


const fetchRestaurants = async (): Promise <IRestaurantCardType[]> => {
  const restaurants = await prisma.restaurant.findMany({
    select: {
      id: true,
      name: true,
      price: true,
      main_img: true,
      location: true,
      cuisine: true,
      slug: true,
      reviews: true,
    }
  });

  return restaurants;
};
```

However, the above code produces two errors. The first error is in the import statement; specifically, trying to import the `Review` type.
`Module '"@prisma/client"' has no exported member 'Review'.ts(2305)`
None of the other imports produce this error.

The other error happens in the `fetchRestaurants` function. Specifically in the `restaurants` object in the `select` property at `reviews: true,`.

```
Type '{ id: true; name: true; price: true; main_img: true; location: true; cuisine: true; slug: true; reviews: true; }' is not assignable to type 'RestaurantSelect'.
  Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'reviews' does not exist in type 'RestaurantSelect'.ts(2322)
```

I'm using Next 13 with the experimental app directory and Prisma for my ORM building on Postgres.

### **Update:**

I was able to delete the `node_modules` and run `npm install` to restore it. That fixed the two errors; however, if I console `restaurants.reviews` I get undefined. And when consoling out the ``` restaurants`` variable the ``` reviews`property returns`reviews: [ [Object] ]```.

Answer (score 2):

- First error might be because you did not migrate after adding `Review` model. you should run

  ```
  npx prisma db push
  ```

From [here](https://www.prisma.io/docs/concepts/components/prisma-migrate/db-push)

> db push uses the same engine as Prisma Migrate to synchronize your
> Prisma schema with your database schema. The db push command:
>
> 1- Introspects the database to infer and executes the changes required
> to make your database schema reflect the state of your Prisma schema.
>
> 2- By default, after changes have been applied to the database schema,
> generators are triggered (for example, Prisma Client). You do not need
> to manually invoke prisma generate.

- yo have prisma generate types, you need to run

  ```
  npx prisma generate
  ```

then you need to restart the server

Comment: I have already ran ```npx prisma db push```. I also changed the function to output a type of ```restaurant``` it still doesn't change the error in the ```select``` property.

Comment: @Ethan if you hover on `restaurants` inside `fetchRestaurants`, what is its type?. is it same as `IRestaurantCardType`

Comment: It's of type ```Restaurant[]``` and I have changed the function to instead output a type of ```Promise <Restaurant[]>```. However, the same error is still there.

Comment: if you go to supabase project db, can you see that all the tables are created. do you see `Reviews` table?

Comment: Yes, there is a reviews table along with all the other tables in the Prisma schema.

Comment: Did you run `npx prisma generate` to generate the types?